# MySQL boolean column not getting updated

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following row:

```
mysql> select * from user\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                   id: 1
             username: crm
             password: AAER8]HR6UnR4knR4YnRnN[]
    accountNonExpired:
     accountNonLocked:
credentialsNonExpired:
              enabled:
              created: 2017-03-12 17:40:25
          createdUser: system
          lastUpdated: NULL
      lastUpdatedUser: NULL
              visible:
              deleted:
          deletedUser: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following command works:

```
mysql> update user set username = 'test' where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from user\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                   id: 1
             username: test
             password: AAER8]HR6UnR4knR4YnRnN[]
    accountNonExpired:
     accountNonLocked:
credentialsNonExpired:
              enabled:
              created: 2017-03-12 17:40:25
          createdUser: system
          lastUpdated: NULL
      lastUpdatedUser: NULL
              visible:
              deleted:
          deletedUser: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the following command to update the 'visible' column does not work:

```
mysql> update user set visible = true where id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from user\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                   id: 1
             username: test
             password: AAER8]HR6UnR4knR4YnRnN[]
    accountNonExpired:
     accountNonLocked:
credentialsNonExpired:
              enabled:
              created: 2017-03-12 17:40:25
          createdUser: system
          lastUpdated: NULL
      lastUpdatedUser: NULL
              visible:
              deleted:
          deletedUser: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the table in question:

```
mysql> show create table user;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user  | CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `accountNonExpired` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `accountNonLocked` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `credentialsNonExpired` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `enabled` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdUser` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdatedUser` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `deletedUser` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the version of Mysql:

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why can I not update the boolean column of my user table?

Edit: The following works:

```
mysql> update user set visible = true where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from user where id = 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                   id: 1
             username: test
             password: AAER8]HR6UnR4knR4YnRnN[]
    accountNonExpired:
     accountNonLocked:
credentialsNonExpired:
              enabled:
              created: 2017-03-12 17:40:25
          createdUser: system
          lastUpdated: NULL
      lastUpdatedUser: NULL
              visible:
              deleted:
          deletedUser: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But did it? There is no visual representation of the value of 'visible' being true or 1?

Comment: I would either set to an explicit `1` or store the value as a `boolean`.

Comment: There might be a problem with displaying bit(1). [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-value-literals.html)  Try this `SELECT id, BIN(visible) as visiblenow FROM user WHERE id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the columns as `0` or `1` for `false` & `true` respectively. The columns are of type bit with default to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the value in visible were already "TRUE""
What happens when you do the following?

If you type the follow and it works then there is your answer

```
update user set visible = false where id = 1;
```